# Compare words ignoring certain characters - Python

Tags: python, list, comparison

I've seen a couple of questions similar to this but none in python. Basically, I want to check if certain words are in a list. Though the words I want to compare might have a ',' which I want to ignore. I have tried this, though it does not ignore the ','.

```py
x = ['hello','there,','person']
y = ['there','person']
similar = [words for words in x if words in y ]
print(similar)
```

**Output**

```
['person']
```

**But I want**

```
['there','person']
```

Does anyone know the simplest way of implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this code use `any function` along with `map` to map containing conditon.

```
x = ['hello','there,','person']
y = ['there','person'] # or take this for more intuation ['there','person','bro']
similar = [words for words in y if any(map(lambda i: i.count(words), x))]
print(similar)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['there', 'person']
```

Comment: However, `y = ['here', 'there']` might produce a less desirable result.

Comment: @rici thanks let me resolve that but also

Comment: For readability you should use `words in i` instead of `i.count(words)`, since all you are testing is whether if `i` contains `words`, not how many occurrences of `words` there are in `i`. For that matter, do not use `lambda` with a `map`. A generator expression would be much more readable, i.e. `any(words in i for i in x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the strings without any comma:

```py
similar = [words for words in x if words.replace(',', '') in y ]
```

**Output**:

```py
>>similar
['there,', 'person']
```

Comment: but wont words.replace mutate the string?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python. `words.replace(',', '')` returns a new string, rather than mutating the original.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers so far require a quadratic time complexity of *O(n x m)*, where *n* and *m* are the lengths of `x` and `y`, respectively.

For a solution that requires just a linear time complexity of *O(n + m)*, you can normalize the strings in `x` to ones without commas and store them as a set, so that you can use set intersection to find common strings with `y`:

```
similar = {word.replace(',' ,'') for word in x}.intersection(y)
```

Comment: Thanks friend, bug was due to initially when was thinking for generalizing the result, then it skip from my mind and I come up with this solution